# Spring boot: forward-headers-strategy has no effect

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have simple rest controller

```
    public void getMyIp(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        final var ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
        ....
    }
```

And I emulate request through proxy server

```
curl --location --request GET 'localhost:8080/api/myIp' \
--header 'X-Forwarded-For: 10.10.10.10' \
--header 'X-Real-Ip: 10.10.10.10'
```

I changed strategy in application.yml

```
server:
    forward-headers-strategy: FRAMEWORK
```

The application runs from IDE with build-in tomcat server.
Why I gets my real ip address?

**UPD: I changed strategy to `native`, and it works now!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It need to use strategy `NATIVE`

```yaml
    server:
        forward-headers-strategy: NATIVE
```

Comment: I have  a sample springdoc https://github.com/vmisra2018/sb-example-swaggerdoc  and I am trying to test with X-Forwarded-For via swgger-ui.html (springdoc plugin beans). I have these configured in my application but when i click on try it out i dont see . For eg : try  /person api